# How to resize Popup size in salesforce Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning, lightning-experience, quickaction

I have created an action which is calling my visualforce page but it's size width is not changing proper. I can set its height from Action button but where to set its width.

i have tried to set width of my visualforce page but when i have checked this page over popup its coming with scrollbar.

[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It is more of a UI issue. Post the html you have used in creating popup

Comment: A bit of code would be nice as said Ashwani. Just randomly you can use .slds-modal--large which you can modified in your own css.